# Provision ILM policy for Elastic Agent (Fleet) streams

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm new to Elastic Agent configuration and running the latest ECK build on Kubernetes.

While I really like to visibility Fleet offers, it seems I'm unable to provision custom ILM policies like I can with Beats, for example:

```
setup.ilm:
      enabled: true
      overwrite: true
      policy_name: "filebeat"
      policy_file: /usr/share/filebeat/ilm-policy.json
      pattern: "{now/d}-000001"
```

Is there a way I can create a policy that does daily rollovers and only keeps the data for 90 days, preferably in code like the above block?

I've tried to add a ilm config to the Elasticsearch config block, but you can't provide this config to Elasticsearch.

```
config:
  node.roles: ["data", "ingest", "remote_cluster_client"]
  setup.ilm:
    enabled: true
    overwrite: true
    policy_name: "logs"
    policy_file: /usr/share/elasticsearch/ilm-policy.json
    pattern: "{now/d}-000001"
```